# How do I create a client server network in Swift, or how do I send a request to another iphone on the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, server, client

I'm trying to create an app like uber, and I'm having trouble with the iphone to iphone connection. How am I to send a request to another Iphone, saying I am your driver! Am I to have riders become accepted, and add them to some database of riders in which drivers can see them? Basically I just want a little explanation on the ways I can use swift to connect iphones, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Miles Singer : Your question gonna be down voted soon for its broad scope but anyway I believe its not wrong in helping the one in need. In uber or any such app not two iPhones communicate peer to peer, There are servers and many other things involved to make them work seamlessly. What you need : You need a web server which will be responsible for hosting web API's which your iPhone apps consume to read and update data at server end. So in short, when your driver registers, your app calls a API in ur server which will add driver info to its db

Comment: Same is the case with customer as well, You need to integrate maps like google maps and need to keep updating your drivers location to server using API depends on how you wanna do it, finally when a customer requests a cab you need to make API call to inform your server that customer needs cab, server finds out the near by cab based on location and then you can use either APNS notifications, GCM notifications, or persistent connection between server and drive device to inform the booking

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a decently long way to go, but let's break this down.

Despite how it may seem, phones don't usually talk directly to each other. In these circumstances, an app will contact a central server in order to get information about things around them. The phone (in your situation) would likely contact the server and request a list of nearby drivers and locations. The server would then send a feed of nearby drivers and their locations so that the phone could display the locations of the drivers.

When you request a ride, your phone will tell the server its current location, and potentially the targeted location. A lot of work is done behind the scenes in the server to schedule a driver to pick you up. The server is keeping track of where a given driver is, how many other clients he has in queue, how long the driver would take to get to you, among many other factors. Once it figures out which driver would be best able to serve you, it will contact that driver and tell him to start moving toward you.

Then the server will contact you saying that it has found a driver, and then will send you the feed as to where that driver is in his progress to get you.

So to more directly answer your question, you'll need to start by setting up a server up to do a lot of the work behind the scenes. You *can* write a server backend in Swift using [Vapor](http://vapor.codes), but server-side swift is in its infancy. I'd also recommend looking into [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) using the Ruby programming language, or [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) using Javascript. But none of these are trivial matters.

Given the nature of your question, the problem you're attempting to solve is certainly a lot more difficult than you've anticipated. But don't let that stop you from asking questions like these.